# How do I get a dataset result for multiple conditions in C#

Tags: c#, select, dataset

I'm trying to add data to a dataset, but I need to check that my new code won't violate the unique indexes.

We're using the Select method to do this:

```
if ((((DataRowView)ttTableBindingSource.Current).IsNew
       || ((DataRowView)ttTableBindingSource.Current).IsEdit)
      && bankingDataSet.ttTable.Select("name = '" + tbxName.Text + "'").Length > 0)
        {
```

That's working fine where the index is unique on name only. However there is another table where the unique index is on name and account.

I'm not sure how to build the syntax for the Select method to handle the 2 fields in one search.

Many thanks

Colin

Comment: It's the same syntax.

bankingDataSet.ttTable.Select("column1 = '" + value1 + "' and column2 = '"  + value2 + "'").Length > 0.
Hth.

Comment: Either I'm not searching well, or the documentation on this method is awful! If I want a 'not equals' condition, do I use `x <> y` or `x != y` or `not x = y`?  Many thanks

Comment: The right operation is x <> y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select("name = '" + tbxName.Text + "' AND account = '" +tbx.Account +"'")
```